# JavaScript. Зачем промис для парсера?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь разобраться в промисах. Есть такой код:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
```

И так `fetch` возвращает промис, мы указываем ему что делать, когда придёт HTTP ответ с сервера, у этого ответа, получается, есть какой-то наследуемый метод `json`, который парсит ответ в объект JS.

Заявляется, что метод `json` возвращает промис, следовательно этот самый промис возвращается колбэком в первом `then`. Что `then` делает с этим возвратом от колбэка, если `then` сам тоже возвращает промис?

Ладно, допустим в цепочке есть новый промис вернувшийся от `response.json` мы вызваем далее по цепочке метод `then` и асинхронно ждём пока HTTP ответ парсится в JS объект. Зачем это нужно делать **асинхронно**?

Насколько я понимаю, код находящийся вне промиса продолжать исполнятся не станет, ведь поток инструкций будет полностью занят парсингом, так ли это?

А если ответ настолько большой, что его парсинг будет занимать десятки секунд, встанет ли 'динамика' остального приложения на это время?

А если представить, что `response.json` не обворачивает парсер в промис, а сразу парсит ответ от сервера, и возвращает JS объект, то есть ли разница в коде сверху от этого?

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
```

Comment: а ты пробовал выполнить код сверху и код в конце вопроса? Получил ли ты одинаковые результаты?

Comment: В реальности первый пример, выведет спарсенный JS объект, второй пример выведет объект-промис вернувшийся от response.json. Для чего парсер пытаются использовать асинхронно, и что then делает с возвратами от колбэков им вызванных (что он в итоге возвращает)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно описанию [fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch)  промис самого fetch разрешается как только сервер пришлет заголовки ответа, но до того, как получено тело ответа. Чтение тела ответа по сети происходит отдельно, вызовом какого либо метода получения результата от request. Тело ответа может быть очень большим и идти по сети частями, тогда и парсер json будет его парсить по мере получения данных. Т.е. он так же вызывает сетевые ожидания. Собственно поэтому любой из методов получения данных из request так же асинхронный.